# How to connect liquibase to AWS RDS Aurora MySQL database

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, liquibase

I am trying to set up liquibase for syncing my dev and prod databases based upon AWS RDS Aurora MySql for a project. Unfortunately I can not get liquibase connected to my AWS Aurora MySQL database.

**What did I do?**

1. Installed liquibase
2. Followed the article https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.Connecting.html which explains how to connect to AWS RDS Aurora MySQL database cluster via JDBC.

   - I downloaded the Maria DB JDBC Connector
   - I configured the liquibase.properties file with data as stated in Appendix 1
   - I ran the command `liquibase --driver=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver --classpath=<PATH_TO_JAR>mariadb-java-client-2.7.1.jar generateChangeLog``
3. liquibase starts as expected and tries to connect to the database prod cluster but then hangs for a while before it terminates with an exception "Communications link failure with primary. No active connection found for master." - see stacktrace in Appendix 2

**My question:**

How do I have to configure liquibase in order to get it running with an AWS RDS Aurora MySQL database cluster?

Thanks and best regards
The Smart Home Maker

**Appendix 1: liquibase.properties:**

```
# Enter the path for your changelog file.
changeLogFile=<CHANGE_LOG_FILENAME>

#### Enter the Target database 'url' information  ####
url=jdbc:mariadb:aurora//<ENDPOINT_URL_FOR_AWS_AURORA_PROD_CLUSTER>:<PORT_FOR_AWS_AURORA_PROD_CLUSTER>/<PROD_DATABASE_NAME>

# Enter the username for your Target database.
username: <PROD_DATABASE_USER>

# Enter the password for your Target database.
password: <PROD_DATABASE_PASSWORD>

#### Enter the Source Database 'referenceUrl' information ####
## The source database is the baseline or reference against which your target database is compared for diff/diffchangelog commands.

# Enter URL for the source database
referenceUrl: jdbc:mariadb:aurora//<ENDPOINT_URL_FOR_AWS_AURORA_DEV_CLUSTER>:<PORT_FOR_AWS_AURORA_DEV_CLUSTER>/<DEV_DATABASE_NAME>

# Enter the username for your source database
referenceUsername: <DEV_DATABASE_USER>

# Enter the password for your source database
referencePassword: <DEV_DATABASE_PASSWORD>

logLevel: DEBUG
```

**Appendix 2: Stacktrace:**

```
[2020-12-29 14:43:05] FEIN [liquibase.servicelocator] Loaded liquibase.license.LicenseService instance liquibase.pro.license.keymgr.DaticalTrueLicenseService
[2020-12-29 14:43:05] INFORMATION [liquibase.integration] No Liquibase Pro license key supplied. Please set liquibaseProLicenseKey on command line or in liquibase.properties to use Liquibase Pro features.
Liquibase Community 4.2.2 by Datical
####################################################
##   _     _             _ _                      ##
##  | |   (_)           (_) |                     ##
##  | |    _  __ _ _   _ _| |__   __ _ ___  ___   ##
##  | |   | |/ _` | | | | | '_ \ / _` / __|/ _ \  ##
##  | |___| | (_| | |_| | | |_) | (_| \__ \  __/  ##
##  \_____/_|\__, |\__,_|_|_.__/ \__,_|___/\___|  ##
##              | |                               ##
##              |_|                               ##
##                                                ## 
##  Get documentation at docs.liquibase.com       ##
##  Get certified courses at learn.liquibase.com  ## 
##  Free schema change activity reports at        ##
##      https://hub.liquibase.com                 ##
##                                                ##
####################################################
Starte Liquibase am 14:43:05 (Version 4.2.2 #36, kompiliert am 2020-12-09 20:07+0000)
[2020-12-29 14:43:05] FEIN [liquibase.integration] 'file:<PATH_TO_JAR_FILE>mariadb-java-client-2.7.1.jar' will be added to Java Classpath.
[2020-12-29 14:43:05] FEIN [liquibase.integration] Liquibase Hub URL:      https://hub.liquibase.com
[2020-12-29 14:43:05] FEIN [liquibase.integration] Liquibase Hub Mode:     all
[2020-12-29 14:43:05] FEIN [liquibase.resource] Adding path <PATH_WHERE_LIQUIBASE_IS_RUNNING>. to resourceAccessor liquibase.resource.FileSystemResourceAccessor
[2020-12-29 14:43:05] FEIN [liquibase.servicelocator] Loaded liquibase.database.Database instance liquibase.database.core.CockroachDatabase
[2020-12-29 14:43:05] FEIN [liquibase.servicelocator] Loaded liquibase.database.Database instance liquibase.database.core.DB2Database
[2020-12-29 14:43:05] FEIN [liquibase.servicelocator] Loaded liquibase.database.Database instance liquibase.database.core.Db2zDatabase
[2020-12-29 14:43:08] FEIN [liquibase.servicelocator] Loaded liquibase.database.Database instance liquibase.database.core.DerbyDatabase
[2020-12-29 14:43:08] FEIN [liquibase.servicelocator] Loaded liquibase.database.Database instance liquibase.database.core.Firebird3Database
[2020-12-29 14:43:08] FEIN [liquibase.servicelocator] Loaded liquibase.database.Database instance liquibase.database.core.FirebirdDatabase
[2020-12-29 14:43:08] FEIN [liquibase.servicelocator] Loaded liquibase.database.Database instance liquibase.database.core.H2Database
[2020-12-29 14:43:08] FEIN [liquibase.servicelocator] Loaded liquibase.database.Database instance liquibase.database.core.HsqlDatabase
[2020-12-29 14:43:08] FEIN [liquibase.servicelocator] Loaded liquibase.database.Database instance liquibase.database.core.InformixDatabase
[2020-12-29 14:43:08] FEIN [liquibase.servicelocator] Loaded liquibase.database.Database instance liquibase.database.core.Ingres9Database
[2020-12-29 14:43:08] FEIN [liquibase.servicelocator] Loaded liquibase.database.Database instance liquibase.database.core.MSSQLDatabase
[2020-12-29 14:43:08] FEIN [liquibase.servicelocator] Loaded liquibase.database.Database instance liquibase.database.core.MariaDBDatabase
[2020-12-29 14:43:08] FEIN [liquibase.servicelocator] Loaded liquibase.database.Database instance liquibase.database.core.MockDatabase
[2020-12-29 14:43:08] FEIN [liquibase.servicelocator] Loaded liquibase.database.Database instance liquibase.database.core.MySQLDatabase
[2020-12-29 14:43:08] FEIN [liquibase.servicelocator] Loaded liquibase.database.Database instance liquibase.database.core.OracleDatabase
[2020-12-29 14:43:08] FEIN [liquibase.servicelocator] Loaded liquibase.database.Database instance liquibase.database.core.PostgresDatabase
[2020-12-29 14:43:08] FEIN [liquibase.servicelocator] Loaded liquibase.database.Database instance liquibase.database.core.SQLiteDatabase
[2020-12-29 14:43:08] FEIN [liquibase.servicelocator] Loaded liquibase.database.Database instance liquibase.database.core.SybaseASADatabase
[2020-12-29 14:43:08] FEIN [liquibase.servicelocator] Loaded liquibase.database.Database instance liquibase.database.core.SybaseDatabase
[2020-12-29 14:43:08] FEIN [liquibase.servicelocator] Loaded liquibase.database.Database instance liquibase.database.core.UnsupportedDatabase
[2020-12-29 14:43:08] FEIN [liquibase.database] Properties:
[2020-12-29 14:43:08] FEIN [liquibase.database] Key:'password' Value:'**********'
[2020-12-29 14:43:08] FEIN [liquibase.database] Key:'user' Value:'***********'
[2020-12-29 14:43:08] FEIN [liquibase.database] Connecting to the URL:'jdbc:mariadb:aurora//jdbc:mariadb:aurora//<ENDPOINT_URL_FOR_AWS_AURORA_PROD_CLUSTER>:<PORT_FOR_AWS_AURORA_PROD_CLUSTER>/<PROD_DATABASE_NAME>' using driver:'org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver'
[2020-12-29 14:43:08] FEIN [liquibase.servicelocator] Loaded liquibase.database.DatabaseConnection instance liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection
[2020-12-29 14:43:08] FEIN [liquibase.servicelocator] Loaded liquibase.database.DatabaseConnection instance com.datical.liquibase.ext.database.jvm.ProJdbcConnection
Unexpected exception when executing liquibase: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Connection could not be created to jdbc:mariadb:aurora//jdbc:mariadb:aurora//<ENDPOINT_URL_FOR_AWS_AURORA_PROD_CLUSTER>:<PORT_FOR_AWS_AURORA_PROD_CLUSTER>/<PROD_DATABASE_NAME> with driver org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.  Communications link failure with primary. No active connection found for master. 
Bitte verwenden Sie die '--logLevel'-Option, um mehr Informationen zu erhalten.
[2020-12-29 15:02:59] FATAL [liquibase.integration] Unexpected Exception when running liquibase: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Connection could not be created to jdbc:mariadb:aurora//jdbc:mariadb:aurora//<ENDPOINT_URL_FOR_AWS_AURORA_PROD_CLUSTER>:<PORT_FOR_AWS_AURORA_PROD_CLUSTER>/<PROD_DATABASE_NAME> with driver org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.  Communications link failure with primary. No active connection found for master. 
liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Connection could not be created to jdbc:mariadb:aurora//jdbc:mariadb:aurora//<ENDPOINT_URL_FOR_AWS_AURORA_PROD_CLUSTER>:<PORT_FOR_AWS_AURORA_PROD_CLUSTER>/<PROD_DATABASE_NAME> with driver org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.  Communications link failure with primary. No active connection found for master. 
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.createDatabaseObject(CommandLineUtils.java:131)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:1409)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main$1.lambda$run$0(Main.java:361)
    at liquibase.Scope.lambda$child$0(Scope.java:160)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:169)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:159)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:138)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:222)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:226)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main$1.run(Main.java:360)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main$1.run(Main.java:193)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:169)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:145)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:193)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:156)
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Connection could not be created to jdbc:mariadb:aurora//jdbc:mariadb:aurora//<ENDPOINT_URL_FOR_AWS_AURORA_PROD_CLUSTER>:<PORT_FOR_AWS_AURORA_PROD_CLUSTER>/<PROD_DATABASE_NAME> with driver org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.  Communications link failure with primary. No active connection found for master. 
    at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.openConnection(DatabaseFactory.java:216)
    at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.openConnection(DatabaseFactory.java:175)
    at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.openDatabase(DatabaseFactory.java:140)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.createDatabaseObject(CommandLineUtils.java:96)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Connection could not be created to jdbc:mariadb:aurora//jdbc:mariadb:aurora//<ENDPOINT_URL_FOR_AWS_AURORA_PROD_CLUSTER>:<PORT_FOR_AWS_AURORA_PROD_CLUSTER>/<PROD_DATABASE_NAME> with driver org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.  Communications link failure with primary. No active connection found for master. 
    at liquibase.database.ConnectionServiceFactory.create(ConnectionServiceFactory.java:36)
    at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.openConnection(DatabaseFactory.java:213)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Connection could not be created to jdbc:mariadb:aurora//jdbc:mariadb:aurora//<ENDPOINT_URL_FOR_AWS_AURORA_PROD_CLUSTER>:<PORT_FOR_AWS_AURORA_PROD_CLUSTER>/<PROD_DATABASE_NAME> with driver org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.  Communications link failure with primary. No active connection found for master. 
    at liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection.open(JdbcConnection.java:43)
    at com.datical.liquibase.ext.database.jvm.ProJdbcConnection.open(Unknown Source)
    at liquibase.database.ConnectionServiceFactory.create(ConnectionServiceFactory.java:33)
    ... 18 more
```

Comment: Where are you running liquibase from? Your laptop? An EC2 instance in the same VPC as the Aurora cluster? What are the security group settings of the Aurora cluster? Is the "publicly accessible" setting enabled on the cluster?

Comment: Hi @MarkB, thank you for the quick comment! I want to run liquibase locally, not on an EC2 instance. Is that possible? I was not aware of the “publicly accessible” option but that’s a good point to look at. So it means either I decide for “closed accessibility” only within the VPC and would therefore need to run liquibase on an EC2 instance OR I decide to run liquibase locally but then have to open the database for public accessibility hence also lose some security safeguard, do I get you right? Thanks and best regards

Comment: Yes you have that correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still looking into that myself, this is a [good article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/rds-code-change-deployment/) provided by a senior technical account manager in AWS to get familiar how things could be connected together.

To sum things up you have to work on AWS ecosystem, deploying Liquibase and CI/CD software like Jenkins on EC2 and commit your SQL repo into AWS codecommit. Note that this generally will work with Aurora but in case of serverless you may encounter issues with connectivity so I suggest you connect it over HTTP through [Data API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/data-api.html) but this is ongoing process I'm still investigating.

Comment: Ok thank you - so I will mark this as accepted answer as I think there is no actual solution to run it locally but only on EC2. Thank you!